# Using lapply in R to loop through a list of data.frames in R

Tags: r, list, dplyr, apply, lapply

I have a dataframe as seen below, image due to size constraints:

[image: bottleneck_list]

So my goal is to take `bottleneck_list` which is a list of dataframes and using lapply, run the same analyses on all dataframes. They are custom but I am struggling to get it to run through each df.

`test` is `bottleneck_list[[1]]`

Here is a sample of the functions

```
  test2 <- test %>% 
  mutate(early_startTime = startTime - 300) %>% 
  mutate(id = rownames(test))

loop <- lapply(1:nrow(test), function(x) {
  neck_row <- test[x,]
  
  test_list <- test[which(test$startTime == bottleneck_row$endTime),]
})
match <- do.call(rbind,loop)

events * match
```

So basically each dataframe must have several operations done to it.

Here's what I tried:

```
list_alt <- lapply(bottleneck_list, sapply, function(x) {

  test <- bottleneck_list[[x]]
  
  test2 <- test %>% 
  mutate(early_startTime = startTime - 300) %>% 
  mutate(id = rownames(test))


loop <- lapply(1:nrow(test), function(x) {
  neck_row <- test[x,]
  
  test_list <- test[which(test$startTime == bottleneck_row$endTime),]
})
match <- do.call(rbind,loop)

match
})
```

But doesn't work. The end result should be all my dataframes from this list be a list of those dataframes with two more variables.

EDIT:
I need to reference `bottleneck_list[[1]]` for this to work.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a a `list` of data.frames, loop over the `list` with `map`, and `mutate` to create new columns in each of the `data.frame`s

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
bottleneck_list2 <- map(bottleneck_list, ~ .x %>%
          mutate(early_startTime = startTime - 300, id = row_number()))
```

---

Or using `lapply` from `base R`

```
bottleneck_list2 <- lapply(bottleneck_list, function(test)
       transform(test, early_startTime = startTime - 300, id = row.names(test)))
```

---

If we want to do some transformations

```
 lapply(bottleneck_list, function(test){
        row.names(test) <- NULL
        test$somecol <- test$col1 + 24
        test
         })
```

Comment: It is a list of dataframes however I dont think this would work since there are several opertations that will happen, updating code now

Comment: @JohnThomas your code for a single data.frame is showed as `test %>% 
  mutate(early_startTime = startTime - 300) %>% 
  mutate(id = rownames(test))`

Comment: Updated to better encapsulate the problem. Basically if I had to do alot of operations to each dataframe, but in the same way.

Comment: @JohnThomas the `events <- do.call(rbind,test2)` is done on a `list` of data.frames.  In the updated code, it is not clear

Comment: The actual operations are for reproducibility (or lack there of) but what I am asking is, can I take a list of data.frames and do any number of the same operations on them all.

Comment: @JohnThomas yes, you can do that and that is how I showed it iin my post.  If I assume that you have `list(mtcars, mtcars) %>% map(~ .x %>% mutate(rn =row_number()))`

Comment: my confusion sparks from your pipes; let's say I had 10 manipulations or so, would I  have to pipe each one separately or a long string of pipes? Because not all operations are related.

Comment: Could you show an example where U maybe summarize and also after that do more manipulation? Basically I can't pipe all my data together because I also reference other datasets.

Comment: @JohnThomas Can you update with a small reproducible example and expected output so that I can test it.  You showed an image and there are some codes around it, which I am finding it not clear because

Comment: @JohnThomas the exact code on your case is not clear to me.  I updated with some changes

Comment: Working on it now but I see the disconnect now. Each element of the list has multiple components, the first [[1]] is the data.frame. See updated OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216679/discussion-between-john-thomas-and-akrun).